# Show the selected-class in first after filter

Tags: javascript, php, html, sorting, html-table

I am trying to sort the students after filter. After filtering the students button classes will change and text as like shown in the below image.

[image]

What I want is student with **select-student** has to come in first then **reject-student** students!  How can I do this..?

PHP->HTML returns like this:

```
<tbody>

<tr>
<td><span><img></span><p>Rasmus1 Lerdorf</p><p><b>Hallticket</b> : S28J1</p></td>
<td style="line-height:45px">4</td>
<td style="line-height:45px">9</td>
<td style="line-height:45px">8</td>
<td style="line-height:45px">4.5</td>
<td><span id="stu28" class="btn btn-danger reject-student selection-class">Not Selected</span></td>
<td style="line-height:45px"><input class="overrideStudent" type="text" name="picomment[28]"></td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td><span><img></span><p>Bill Gates</p><p><b>Hallticket</b> : S29J1</p></td>
<td style="line-height:45px">9</td>
<td style="line-height:45px">10</td>
<td style="line-height:45px">8</td>
<td style="line-height:45px">6.1</td>
<td><span id="stu28" class="btn  selection-class btn-success select-student">Selected</span></td>
<td style="line-height:45px"><input class="overrideStudent" type="text" name="picomment[29]"></td>
</tr>

</tbody>
```

This is the Javascript code to select student:

```
success: function (response) {
    $(".selection-class").addClass('btn-danger reject-student');
    $(".selection-class").removeClass('btn-success select-student');
    $(".selection-class").text('Not Selected');
    $.each(response['students'], function(k, student) {
        $("#stu"+student.student_id).removeClass('btn-danger reject-student');
        $("#stu"+student.student_id).addClass('btn-success select-student');
        $("#stu"+student.student_id).text('Student Selected');
    });
    $("#success_message").show();
    $("#success_message").html(response['message']);
```

Comment: Isn't it better to do this on server side?

Comment: Actually it is not possible from server side because filters are haapening through Ajax call in response array coming which will select the students.. with that filter criteria, @Armin

Comment: I suppose before showing information to users, you already have that information on server side. Maybe in your db ("order by" in sql queries), or in your response arrays (sort array), or any other way. It is possible to do this on client side, but I think it's better if you have reusable list on server side, without the need for additional client side tweaking. I may be wrong, however... @Abid

Comment: _“how can i do this..?”_ – you should _start_ by doing some proper research. https://www.google.com/search?q=how+to+sort+elements+in+dom

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can  [append()](http://api.jquery.com/append/) class "reject-student" to its parent selector and get needed result.