# Group table rows based on classname

Tags: javascript, html, sorting, filter, html-table

I would like to be able to sort the rows in a table by classname, so that all rows with class `selected` appear first and `rejected` appear last.

For clarification, I would like to transform this

```
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr><td><span class="selected">WAHEED</span></td></tr>
    <tr><td><span class="selected">DON</span></td></tr>
    <tr><td><span class="rejected">JACK</span></td></tr>
    <tr><td><span class="selected">MARK</span></td></tr>
    <tr><td><span class="rejected">GATEES</span></td></tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

into something like this:

```
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr><td><span class="selected">WAHEED</span></td></tr>
    <tr><td><span class="selected">MARK</span></td></tr>
    <tr><td><span class="selected">DON</span></td></tr>
    <tr><td><span class="rejected">JACK</span></td></tr>
    <tr><td><span class="rejected">GATEES</span></td></tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Do notice the change in order between both code samples.
Any idea on how I can achieve this?

Comment: What have you tried so far? If you haven't tried anything then I cannot help you are you don't have a specific problem with your source code other than not writing anything.

Comment: i want to know how can i do that then only i can try.

Comment: @NewToJS please look at this question once this one is similar to mine: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41978354/show-the-selected-class-in-first-after-filter?noredirect=1#comment71136089_41978354

Comment: Well the answer(s) below show you how to *"How to sort table with class name"* now it's down to you to impliment this into your existing source code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do it:

```js
var rows = document.querySelectorAll('table.sorted tr');
for (i = 0; i < rows.length; i++) {
  if (rows[i].querySelector('span.rejected')) {
      rows[i].closest('tbody').appendChild(rows[i]);
      }
}
```

```html
<table class="sorted">
<tbody>
<tr><td> 1. </td><td><span class="selected">WAHEED</span></td></tr>
<tr><td> 2. </td><td><span class="selected">DON</span></td></tr>
<tr><td> 3. </td><td><span class="rejected">JACK</span></td></tr>
<tr><td> 4. </td><td><span class="selected">MARK</span></td></tr>
<tr><td> 5. </td><td><span class="rejected">GATEES</span></td></tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

It runs on all `<table>`s in page with the class of `sorted` and places `<tr>`s containing a span with the class of `rejected` last (so all the others remain above). Feel free to modify it to suit your needs, it's pretty straight forward.

Comment: Awesome let me try i hope it works for me... @Andrei

Comment: Please note in the question your `HTML` code has an error: the `<tbody>` tag is started as `<tbode>`. That will make any solution you try fail, because there is no valid `<tbody>` on your table. Although some browsers (i.e. Chrome), when your `<table>` doesn't have a valid `<tbody>` automatically add one. This is not true for all browsers, though, don't rely on it.

Comment: see this question once i need similar like this after responce how can i do that..? : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41978354/show-the-selected-class-in-first-after-filter?noredirect=1#comment71136089_41978354     @Andrei

Comment: @LyndaCarter the answer I have provided is purposefully coded for readability, so you could understand its logic and implement it in your own application with ease. StackOverflow's mission is to help  programmers improve their coding skills and better understand coding principles. Providing free programming services is not part of SO's mission. If what you need are programming services, I suggest you hire a programmer.

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean something like this

```
 var people, asc1 = 1,
        asc2 = 1,
        asc3 = 1;
    window.onload = function () {
        people = document.getElementById("people");
    }

    function sort_table(tbody, col, asc) {
        var rows = tbody.rows,
            rlen = rows.length,
            arr = new Array(),
            i, j, cells, clen;
        // fill the array with values from the table
        for (i = 0; i < rlen; i++) {
            cells = rows[i].cells;
            clen = cells.length;
            arr[i] = new Array();
            for (j = 0; j < clen; j++) {
                arr[i][j] = cells[j].innerHTML;
            }
        }
        // sort the array by the specified column number (col) and order (asc)
        arr.sort(function (a, b) {
            return (a[col] == b[col]) ? 0 : ((a[col] > b[col]) ? asc : -1 * asc);
        });
        // replace existing rows with new rows created from the sorted array
        for (i = 0; i < rlen; i++) {
            rows[i].innerHTML = "<td>" + arr[i].join("</td><td>") + "</td>";
        }
    }
```

http://codepen.io/_adamjw3/pen/pRaXBg

Comment: No i want like All male students in one place and Female at one place. `sort by class name`

Comment: see this question once i need similar thing: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41978354/show-the-selected-class-in-first-after-filter?noredirect=1#comment71136089_41978354